# Making SPNEGO http calls from a C# client

Tags: c#, authentication, windows-authentication, kerberos

I am pretty new to C#. We have a Tomcat REST service which has a SPNEGO http filter in front of it. How can I access this service and pass along my Kerberos information?

Comment: Are you trying to access this service in an ASP .NET application?

Comment: @alainlompo No, it's a WPF application talking to my REST service.

Answer (score 0):

If you use plain `HttpClient` in .NET, just set `DefaultNetworkCredentials` and you are done.

Comment: But it doesn't pop up a window to let user enter user name and password.

Comment: @machinarium ...and it won't because it uses the default ones. The popup is your task.

Comment: What should i use when it's the HttpWebReuqest instead of HttpClient?

Comment: You should try that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/71b57yke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx